# How to  convert EAR as executable file?

Tags: java, web-services, jboss

I have no idea about converting EAR file into exe(Executable file), Where are i am working with jboss and i developing webservices. I want to give my product as executable file . Can anybody has idea about this.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Gobi, you've already posted [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9715350/issue-in-making-exe-of-ear) regarding this on 15th March, to which you've got no response. I guess you've just rephrased that same question here.

Might I suggest asking your customer/client how she would like the web service 'ear' delivered? I'm also guessing you might have database scripts, properties/config files etc. I'd put my money on 'a zip containing the ear, database scripts (if any) with related documentation'

There is no way a customer would want to 'double click' your ear and have it installed directly onto a server. If you read your Java EE spec correctly, you'd find a 'deployer' role in there. Its not there for fun. Its a very serious role whose responsibilities include 'configuring' your application.

Think about it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about making EAR as executable.
There is a editor which converts your project into setup file or installer for windows .

Hope this helps.

I used NSIS editor and recommend it and it only creates installer for windows.

[HM NSIS Editor](http://hmne.sourceforge.net/).

you may also have look at [izpack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IzPack)

Comment: I remember yes it is free tool

Comment: Thank you , Do have any idea how usually MNC people deliver their EAR to customer

Comment: it depends,we used to uploaded our EAR to client's machine by FTP

Comment: The location of the sever location and other will u search batch file to search or you will directly get from users

Comment: we used to get from the users

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9493/discussion-between-gobi-and-balaswamy-vaddeman)

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want customers/users/whatever to just be able to double-click on your file, and there's a web server up and running? While that would be *possible*, it's not really the way most people want to run web services. They're very likely to want to run your web service within an existing container, configuring it alongside other services.

An EAR file is already designed to be pretty much droppable within a container, so that's fine. You could *also* supply a zip file (or an installer) with a *sample* container setup using any of the free container implementations - either preconfigured with some reasonable default values (e.g. for the port) or running through an installer wizard. I wouldn't spend too much time on it though - I'd assume that most people who want to run a web service will already have some experience of setting up a container, or will have specific requirements you couldn't easily capture in a wizard without a *lot* of work.

Comment: My target is delivery my product should be wrapper , I want to give my product more secured so i am using web service, Once customer double on my product it should search the server location and will install or place my EAR  in the server location

Comment: @Gobi: What do you mean by "the server location"? Which server? If the user knows where the server is, why haven't they put the EAR file there themselves?

Comment: Server is jboss server , And we have to place the Ear in deploy location. To ease there work and we the product installation and configuration more efficient , we support to get the server location from user as input and will place the EAR in running server location .

Comment: @Gobi: Then that sounds like you just want a setup installer (e.g. using the tool linked in Balaswamy's answer). Although to be honest, if the user's going to provide that location anyway, does it *actually* save them any time to browse to it within an installer rather than within their own file system explorer?

Comment: Ok usually how you will provide EAR to customer . I am asking product delivery

Comment: @Gobi: I'm  not in the business of providing EARs to anyone - I'm just making the point that copying a file into a directory is as easy as running an installer which then asks you for that very same directory...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9491/discussion-between-gobi-and-jon-skeet)

Comment: @Gobi: Sorry, I don't do chat - it doesn't fit in with the way I work.